# Express: unable to access POST data and set cookie at the same time

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I'm writing an application that takes in a post request and sets a cookie pulled from the POST info. I'm stuck in a catch 22. In the first code sample I can set the cookie but can't access the data, in the second I can access the data but can't set the cookie. I'm sure I'm missing some basic concept of how the middle ware works but I can't for the life of me find the info I need.

The code below creates the cookie as expected but my post variable become undefined

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , handshake = require('./routes/handshake')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();   
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride()); 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var cookie = req.cookies.cokkieName;
    console.log("cookie_name" , cookie);
    if (cookie === undefined)
    {
            //cookie is set but I can't use req.post.xxxx. It"s always undefined
        res.cookie("price", 111, { maxAge: 10000 });
        console.log('cookie has been created successfully');
    } 
    else
    {
        console.log('cookie exists', cookie);
    } 
    next();
});

app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.post('/handshake', handshake.token);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The following code executes the setCookie callback (because the console output shows up), and on the console the variables are properly defined, but the cookie is not set.

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , handshake = require('./routes/handshake')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());


var setCookie = function (req, res, next) {
    var cookie = req.cookies.cokkieName;
    console.log("cookie_name" , cookie);
    if (cookie === undefined)
    {

        res.cookie("price", 111, { maxAge: 10000 }); 
            //in the console the post.body.xxxx data appears correctly but no cookie!!!
        console.log('cookie has been created successfully',post.body.xxx);
    } 
    else
    {
        console.log('cookie exists', cookie);
    } 
    next();
};
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.post('/handshake', setCookie ,handshake.token);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Trying to make the code more readable introduced too many typos that weren't relevant to my code. I took the suggestion and changed the code in the following way but it still doesn't write a cookie to the client.

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , handshake = require('./routes/handshake')
  , http = require('http')
  , crypt = require('crypto')
  , io = require('socket.io')
  , db = require('levelup')('./mydb')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var cookieMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
    var cookie = req.cookies.user;
    console.log("cookie_name" , cookie);
    if (cookie === undefined)
    {
        // no: set a new cookie
        var random = Math.random().toString();
        random=random.substring(2,random.length);       
        sessionToken = Date.now()  + random;
        salt = sessionToken + req.body.address;
        sha2 = crypt.createHash('sha256');
        sha2.update(sessionToken);
        var price = req.body.price;
        var encryptedSession = sha2.digest('hex');

    console.log('post body',price );
        res.cookie('user','price' , { maxAge: 100000 });
        console.log('existing cookies', req.cookies);
    } 
    else
    {
        console.log('cookie exists', req.cookies);
    } 
    next(); 
};
//development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.session({secret: "TheSuperSecretStringForHashing"}));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
//app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.post('/handshake', cookieMiddleware , handshake.token);
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


 var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

io = io.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
      socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

The handshake.js handler

```
exports.token = function(req, res){
    req.body.title = 'Payment Portal';
    res.render('payment_init', req.body);
};
```

Comment: I only scanned the code briefly but since you are using global middleware for the cookie could it be that an other request is setting it before the post request? For example a favicon request also gets handled by global middleware unless you end that request before the cookie middleware. It's the same reason why you should put your static middleware at the top (which you didn't). So for a static file your cookie middleware is running as well. If you want to run the cookie middleware only on the '/handshake' route you can do app.post('/handskake', cookieMiddleware, handskake.token).

Comment: Hi @Pickels thanks for the response. I'm having a little trouble understanding a couple of your points. "...a favicon request also gets handled by global middleware unless you end that request before the cookie middleware". I actually do have global favicon before the cookie (I removed it to make the code more readable), but I'm not clear what you mean by "end that request".  Also, "for a static file your cookie middleware is running as well.". I'm not clear why this is bad. If it's run with a static file then the cookie should be set. Isn't this what I want to have happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something else I noticed is that you use req.post.xxx it should be req.body.xxx. With 'end that request' I mean that if middleware does it's thing and the following middleware doesn't have to handle anything else it will end the request and not call next. So in case of static middleware when it finds that your url matches a file on disk it will serve that file and not call next. That way you don't run extra middleware which has nothing to do with serving static files.

Comment: @Pickels, I took your suggestion and changed the code to the following app.post('/handshake', cookieMiddleware , handshake.token);    The cookieMiddleware function is executed and I can read the req.body.price varible (can see it in the console) BUT the cookie is still not being sent to the client. Furthermore, when I do console.log(res) right after setting the cookie, I can see this   _headers:  { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
     'set-cookie': 'user=price; Max-Age=100; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 27 Apr 2013 05:01:54 GMT' }        So why isn't the cookie showing up on the client?

Comment: @user1822910 you're not using `res.writeHead` somewhere in `handshake.token`, are you?

Comment: @robertklep, no. I just edited my code to include the full handshake.token function

Comment: @Boso I created a very simple gist that mimics your code (https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5472648) and that seems to work just fine: it can both read the price from `req.body` and also sets a cookie.

Comment: @robertklep, thanks for the help. referring to your gist I started commenting out code in my main app until it looked like yours. It generated the cookie and data as expected. I then started adding back elements one by one until I found the one blocking. For whatever reason I re-added all elements and it's still working.That annoys me a little bit because it means there was some typo somewhere I must have corrected but wasn't aware of. Anyway, I appreciate the effort. Also thanks to Pickels.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for a cookie named `cokkieName`, but the cookie you are setting has the name `price`.

Try changing this to:

```
var cookie = req.cookies.price;
```

`cookie` should now contain your cookie value.

Comment: Yeah that's a typo, but still it doesn't explain why I wasn't able to access the post data. I'm pretty sure Pickles response to my question explains what happened but I'm still reading the documentation trying to fully grok his answer.